# Does animation on Android change depending on the IDE?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I imported a project from **Intellij (pre-Gradle structure)** to **Android Studio** (latest version) by simply copying the files into a new project and making the corresponding changes necessary (loading libs, changing package names, etc.)

It works nearly perfectly except for there's a **bug** with all the **animations** and **placements of views**.

Can this be a problem depending on the **IDE** or is there something wrong with my code? (I tried the code in Intellij and it worked perfectly after importing the problems occur).

Thank you very much in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The IDE itself changes nothing about how an application is built or runs. The IDE exists to provide a convenient way of viewing and editing your code.

The most likely culprits are using different versions of the build tools or using different versions of libraries.